# XML fields not getting transfered to local server

Tags: xsd

I have a web service hosted on VS2010 for local testing. My issue is not every element of my soap request is getting passed to the server. What could be a possible issue and resolution?

Really appreciate your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing an object, make sure it is serializable.